# From the controller, how do I get the users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC and have a question. The Visual Studio template creates a table `dbo.AspNetUsers` that has a column called `Id`. From my controller I want to get that value for the user who is signed in

```
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {

        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) // if not logged in 
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
             string thisUserId = ???
             // do something with thisUserId
        }
```

I've looked through the source files but can't figure out how I get this.

Comment: Are you using membership provider?

Answer (score 1):

This works in my project (which uses the `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`)

```
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
string userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);
object providerUserKey = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
string thisUserId = providerUserKey.ToString();
```

Comment: The `userId` is of type `nvarchar`.Why are you casting it to a `Guid` and back into a `string` again?

Comment: I suspect I'm using an earlier version of Asp.NET Membership then you, and this is storing the UserId as a `uniqueidentifier`. I'll take that part out of the code example.